# Spring CorsFilter CorsConfiguration Allow Multiple origins

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

im working in spring projet where i want to allow multiple origins call my backen API.
so far my config works only for one origin. and this is my code :

```
  @Bean
  public CorsFilter corsFilter() {

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

    config.addAllowedOriginPattern("myoriginone");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
  }
```

do you have any idea how i can allow multiple origins. something like "host1","host2".. since the addAllowedOriginPattern() method accept only one string param.

Regards.

Comment: by looking in the api? https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.html#setAllowedOriginPatterns-java.util.List-

Comment: Likewise, the Javadoc for `addAllowedOriginPattern`: "Variant of setAllowedOrigins for adding one origin at a time". Meaning you can just call `addAllowedOriginPattern` multiple times to add multiple origin patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the docs, the `allowedOrigins` is an array.

```
@Nullable
private List<String> allowedOrigins;
```

and the following method is setting the allowed Origins. Clearly, you can invoke the method multiple times to add the different origins.

```
    /**
     * Add an origin to allow.
     */
    public void addAllowedOrigin(String origin) {
        if (this.allowedOrigins == null) {
            this.allowedOrigins = new ArrayList<>(4);
        }
        else if (this.allowedOrigins == DEFAULT_PERMIT_ALL) {
            setAllowedOrigins(DEFAULT_PERMIT_ALL);
        }
        this.allowedOrigins.add(origin);
    }
```

***OR***

Use the following

```
public void setAllowedOrigins(@Nullable List<String> allowedOrigins) {
        this.allowedOrigins = (allowedOrigins != null ? new ArrayList<>(allowedOrigins) : null);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Environment variable is the better practice. To add multiple origins. Place the variable in `application.properties` file

```
regions=http://localhost:8080, http://localhost:8081, http://a.b.c.d, http://localhost:9000
```

Create a global variable like this

```
@Value("${regions}")
private String[] allowedOrigins;
```

Now call this as

```
 @Override
 public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry)
 {
     registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins);
 }
```